# Exceptions in .gitignore do not exclude files in subfolders

Tags: git, gitignore

When I run `git status` it seems that it's only tracking files that have been modified but not new files in subfolders.

This is pretty much my .gitignore:

```
# Ignore everything
*

# But this files that i want to track
!.config/
!.fonts/
!.bashrc
!.gitignore
!.profile
!.Xresources
!.vimrc
!.zshrc

!README.md
```

It is in my `$HOME`.
If I create a new file in directories `.fonts/` or `.config/` it seems like git is ignoring them. But it does track files like `.vimrc` or `.zshrc`

I tried to open this repo with GitKraken and it works how I'm expecting.
I only have this error when I run `git status` in command line

Comment: Note that modified files that are already committed are not ignored because they are already tracked, not because of any coincidental matches with exclusion rules.

Answer (score 1):

You could prefix these patterns with two asterisks (`**`) to match these files in any directory:

```
!**/.config/
!**/.fonts/
!**/.bashrc
!**/.gitignore
!**/.profile
!**/.Xresources
!**/.vimrc
!**/.zshrc

!**/README.md
```